# JSF and Jquery- How to target an element that is rendered after an ajax call

Tags: jquery, jsf-2.2, jcrop

I have a form that contains a p:fileUpload component as well as an h:graphicImage component. The h:graphicImage component is only rendered once the file has been uploaded via AJAX.

My problem is that I need to execute Jcrop(an image-cropping library) after the file has been uploaded, but the image that I need to execute JCrop on is rendered via ajax and so doesn't exist at when the document is ready

I have something vaguely like this:

```
<form>
  <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{personController.uploadFile}" />
  <h:graphicImage id="profilePicture" value="images/#{personController.uploadedFile}" rendered="#{personController.fileUploaded}" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {  
     //Wont get called due to partial page refresh 
     $('#profilePicture').JCrop()
 })
</script>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a form then you should add the form ID to the element. In JSF the elements in form gets a form's ID as a prefix. So, you can inspect the element and use this way:

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function ( e, x, s){
    if(s.url === 'uploadurl'){
         $('#formID\\:profilePicture').JCrop();
    }
 });
```

Here in the ajax complete event in the callback the arguments are `event, xhr, settings`.

Comment: Sorry use I actually used the prependId="false" attribute on the form so that it doesn't prepend the form id. 

Thanks for the solution ! I will try it out and let you know!